# Missing parameter error

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm new in play framework and I'm trying to do a simple post to server.
In my routes I set:

```
POST    /Hello/add          controllers.Hello.add(name)
```

In my Hello.java class I set:

```
public class Hello extends Controller {
    public static Result add(String name){
        //add code
    }
}
```

And in my html file:

```
<form action="Hello/add" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

But when I click on the button 'Add', is lauched the following exception:

```
For request 'POST /Hello/add' [Missing parameter: name]
```

Someone knows why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a [DynamicForm](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaForms) in your Action, and to do not specify any parameter in the route file:

The route:

```
POST    /Hello/add          controllers.Hello.add()
```

The controller and action:

```
public class Hello extends Controller {
    public static Result add(){
        DynamicForm requestData = form().bindFromRequest();
        String name = requestData.get("name");
        // do what you want with the name variable
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there another way? Play don't do it?

Comment: form() is now deprecated. Use FormFactory instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099834/the-method-formclasst-from-form-class-is-deprecated-in-play-framework

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to provide the name parameter in the method signature in the route file for the binding to work.

In the route file, play don't understand where the name parameter come from as you don't specify it in the route pattern

Comment: I didn't get it.. I tried to remove the parameter in route file but another error ocurrs: not enough arguments for method add: (name: java.lang.String)play.mvc.Result.

Answer (score 0):

As [previously told](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11608115/365237), DynamicForm needs to be used if the form data does not relate to a Model. However, if it does relate to a Model (as should be the usual case), you'd do it this way:

```
public class Hello extends Controller {
    public static Result add(){
        Form<MyObject> inputObject = form(MyObject.class).bindFromRequest();
        // do what you want with the prefilled object
        // object is accessible through inputObject.get()
        // often you'd just inputObject.get().save();
    }
}
```

Here MyObject extends Model.

You'd still have routes without parameters though, so this applies:

```
POST    /Hello/add          controllers.Hello.add()
```